# Split filebeat message field into multiple fields in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, split, field, kibana, filebeat

I've the following data for the `message` field which is being shipped by filebeat to elasticseatch. I am not using Logstash here

```
2020-09-20 15:44:23 ::1 get / - 80 - ::1 mozilla/5.0+(windows+nt+10.0;+win64;+x64)+windows/537.36+(khtml,+like+gecko)+chrome/85.0.4183.102+chrome/537.36 - 200 0 0 10
```

I want to split the above data at every space and assign them to different fields and the new fields should get reflect in the kibana discovery portal.

How can we do that?

I've tried to use scripted field in kibana, but I am unable to achieve it as I am not aware of scripted field querying.

Comment: Hi, @chand, have you checked my answer? Did it get you started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch and use the Grok processor to parse your `message` field into multiple fields. Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/grok-processor.html

For example, based on your log:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description" : "...",
    "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "message",
          "patterns": ["%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{DATA} %{WORD:request.method} %{DATA:request.url} - %{NUMBER:port} %{GREEDYDATA:useragent} - %{NUMBER:response.status_code} %{GREEDYDATA}"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs":[
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "2020-09-20 15:44:23 ::1 get / - 80 - ::1 mozilla/5.0+(windows+nt+10.0;+win64;+x64)+windows/537.36+(khtml,+like+gecko)+chrome/85.0.4183.102+chrome/537.36 - 200 0 0 10"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not using logstash here, so without logstash does grok processor? Also '2020-09-20 15:44:23 ::1 get / - 80 - ::1 mozilla/5.0+(windows+nt+10.0;+win64;+x64)+windows/537.36+(khtml,+like+gecko)+chrome/85.0.4183.102+chrome/537.36 - 200 0 0 10"' is not static every time. The value of message field changes. So how do we pass the message field dinamically?

Comment: That is not Logstash, that is an ingest pipeline set in Elasticsearch. Please check the link I shared in the answer. And as for the dynamicity of the `message`'s value, the grok processor is made to support it. You can define different patterns, optional fields, etc. You need to investigate a bit in what are the possibilities of grok.

Comment: Sure I will investigate it and update the result here.

Comment: I've investigated a lot but couldn't find the suitable doc for the dynamicity of message's field value. can you please point me to the suitable doc? 
I am bit new to ELK stack so couldn't able to understand in depth concepts of grok processor now.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://www.elastic.co/blog/structuring-elasticsearch-data-with-grok-on-ingest-for-faster-analytics .

Comment: yeah I've referred the doc shared by you and other docs too, everywhere I could see the static value they are referring. Unable to find how do we pass the dynamic value of a message field? also are these fields get's visible in kibana Discovery portal?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by static value. With a grok processor you specify the doc field to parse (e.g., `message`) and the parsing rules (e.g., `%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} ...`) that apply to the value of that field - which changes with the document. Once you set the grok proc. in an ingest pipeline, the matching patterns are extracted into new fields, also visible in discovery. But all I just said it's better explained in the docs I linked: read it once more! (www.elastic.co/blog/structuring-elasticsearch-data-with-grok-on-ingest-for-faster-analytics , section "Using grok to structure data")